# Problem implementing declarative transactions

Tags: grails, transactions, declarative

I want to implement transaction control at the function level. What i want is something like this.

> class MyService{
>
> static transactional = false
>
> @Transactional(readOnly = false,
>   propagation =
>   Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
>
> public def saveCountry(){ Country co =
>   new Country(name:'mycountry')
>   co.save() createState()
>
> }
>
> @Transactional(readOnly = false,
>   propagation =
>   Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
>
> public def createState(){
>       State state = new State(name:'state')
>       state.save()    throw new RuntimeException()
>       } }

What i want is that createState() creates a new transaction independent of the saveCountry(),such that if createState() fails,

the country object already saved is not revoked. Though I ve given the annotations but they dont produce the desired effect. A single transaction 
is created here, and it is revoked when the exception is thrown.None of the object is saved.

Can anybody help

Comment: It looks like a Grails bug. File a JIRA issue here : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS

Comment: I had the same problem - here is the solution:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Declarative-transactions-don-t-works-in-1-3-x-tp2308918p2309028.html

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend taking this approach. When you reach the createState() method, grails will attempt to use any open transactions before creating a new one if none are available.

Instead I would just use small transaction blocks that surround only the necessary grails code instead of trying to declare the methods transactional

http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html

for example I can have a block anywhere such as

```
State.withTransaction { status -> 
   //all the code in here has an explicit transaction   
}
```

This transaction either flushes or rolls back at the end of the block and the transaction has a reference to a spring object TransactionStatus. This gives you fine grain control on error handling.   This will allow you to have large transactional blocks but still decide when and where transactions end.

I would change the code to

```
public def saveCountry() {
    Country.withTransaction { status ->
        Country co = new Country(name:'mycountry')
        co.save()
    }
    createState()
}

public def createState(){
    State.withTransaction { status ->
        State state = new State(name:'state')
        state.save()
        throw new Exception
    }  
}
```

In this case the country will be saved but the state's transaction will be rolled back